# Are those regular expressions define the same language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions, multisets

I have two questions. Are those regular expressions are the same?

(1) b*(ab*)* and (b*a)*b *

(2) b*(aaab*)* and (b*aaa) * b*

I feel like they both create language that have worlds palindrome. Is that right? In the first one, both *a*'s are must and *b's* are *zero or unlimited*. The second one is the same. the string *aaa* is a must in both and b's are *zero or unlimited.*

Am I right?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41797205/781723, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2109538/14578, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/69162/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has been asked and answered on (multiple) other SE sites at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both regular expressions in (1) define the same language, and it's the language of all possible words in the alphabet $\{a,b\}$, i.e. all possible finite strings consisting of letters $a$ and $b$. (So no, it's not the language of palindromes.) In particular, note that $a$ may not be present in these words at all, because of the Kleene star on $(ab^*)$ — meaning that this entire group may be used zero times, thus producing words of the form $b^*$, i.e. words of arbitrary length consisting of $b$ only.

Similarly, both expression in (2) define the same language, and it's the language of words where $a$'s only appear in groups of three (or any multiples of three).